# How to view Nginx request string?

Tags: nginx

I'm not sure how to view the request string in Nginx, for example a GET/POST request.

In context; if I wanted to block mySQL injection attacks:

```
if($query_string ~ /(\%27)|(\')|(\-\-)|(\%23)|(#)/ix)
{
    return 403;
}
```

Does anyone know how to/the variable that it's under?

Comment: Nginx is not appropriate place for that. Your server shuld be responsible for this

Comment: Use WAF such as naxsi, or Mod_Security.